# Como comparar minhas edições com o repositório do Github no Intellij

Tags: github, intellij-idea, phpstorm

No *PHP Storm* eu tenho uma janela `version control` onde aparecem as modificações que eu fiz, selecionando, tenho uma opção `show diff`, assim posso rever todas as mudanças entre o que está no repositório e o que eu fiz, antes de fazer `commit`. No *Intellij* não estou encontrando essa opção. Alguém sabe onde ela se encontra? Como faço para usá-la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No intellij existe também esta janela `version control`, pode ser acessada com o atalho `alt+9`.

Uma dica é usar o `ctrl+shift+a` (keymap linux) para pesquisar coisas do intellij no intellij.

[image: printcreen intellij]